# Main (html tag) containing header

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I'm confusing. I read diferents opinions about main. The first one says that main (as it's the principal section) could contain header and footer as direct children.

```
<main>
    <header></header>
    <section>for the content</section> 
</main>
```

Others says that main can't contain header as direct children, instead use article or section as parent. So the result would be:

```
<main>
    <article>
        <header></header>
        <section>for the content</section>
    </article>
</main>
```

Currently I have this layout, but I'm confused if It's necessary to add an article or a section to wrapp the header and the content:

[image]

Comment: The only test that's on-topic here is whether it is HTML valid. You can run the snippets through an HTML validator to establish this for yourself.

Comment: It's for semantic and accessibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after more research it's seems to be ok to use main with header as a direct children. [image]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main

If I understand this, main could be parent of any flow content.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content

Answer (score 1):

According to those documentations `<main>` can contain self `<header>` like `<article>`. But `<header>` of `<main>` should be separate/independent of the `<header>` of the `<body>` of the page:

1. The `<header>` element defines a banner landmark when its context is the `<body>` element. The HTML header element is not considered a banner landmark when it is descendant of an `<article>`, `<aside>`, **`<main>`**, `<nav>`, or `<section>` element.
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header#accessibility_concerns
2. When the main content of the page (i.e. excluding footers, headers, navigation blocks, and sidebars) is all one single self-contained composition, that content may be marked with an article, **but it is technically redundant in that case** (since it's self-evident that the page is a single composition, as it is a single document).
   https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-article-element

P.S.
The only remark to what you wrote "*that main (as it's the principal section)*". The `<main>` element is not a sectioning element like `<article>` or `<section>`. The `<main>` HTML element represents the dominant content of the  of a document. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main

Answer (score -2):

**Both variants available**.
Do what you prefer more, I like first variant.

I am not sure in format of your work. If it is theoretical use: [MDN Library](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML)

If it is practical, make sure that it is working and readable.

Do not worry as much as you are doing about tags. Every tag ususally worth nothing, only browsers characterise tags. If you want - you can even create your own tag.

For example:

```
<style>
  main-header{display: block;}
  heading-large{display:inline; font: 700 1.5em system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; color: #111; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
</style>

<main-header>

  <heading-large>
    It is working
  </heading-large>

</main-header>
```

But you will need to characterize it in css and there are will be a lot more problems that you will need to solve with going through, but they are miserable for not corporate projects.

```css
main-header{display: block;}
heading-large{display:inline; font: 700 1.5em system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; color: #111; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

```html
<main-header>

  <heading-large>
    It is working
  </heading-large>

</main-header>
```

Comment: But it's suppose to use the tags for semantic and accessibility, css not apply there.

Comment: If you will see some examples of best practices for semantics - it is just div.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen best practices say just use a div... that just seems like the easiest practice. You were right @STUCKED in wanting to maintain semantics and accessibility